# pipe to program email script not working

Tags: php, email, pipe

i have inserted following link to pipe the emails.
link: public_html/emailer.php
i have script file in public_html folder, the following script i am using:
it should create a file in the directory, but its not working.

```
#!/public_html/ -q
<?php
/* Read the message from STDIN */
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = ""; // This will be the variable holding the data.
while (!feof($fd)) {
$email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);
/* Saves the data into a file */
$fdw = fopen("pipemail.txt", "w");
fwrite($fdw, $email);
fclose($fdw);
/* Script End */
?>
```

[this is how i am setting pipe to program path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmViI.png)

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: its not creating the file, which means somehow the script is not running at all, or i have error in first line of the script. i don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
  $fd = fopen("php://stdin","r");
  $email = "";
  while (!feof($fd)) {
      $email .= fread($fd,1024);
  }
  fclose($fd);
  /* Saves the data into a file */
  $fdw = fopen("pipemail.txt", "w");
  fwrite($fdw, $email);
  fclose($fdw);
?>
```

Make sure it has unix line [`\n`] ending while you put the code in your server.
Also make sure the script has permission to execute!

Comment: sorry, where to add unix line? at the end like this [\r]?

Comment: First try to use the above code. It already has Unix line ending.

Comment: not working... if i run the script through url, it does create a file, but when i send an email to one of my domain emails, it does't runs the script.

Comment: Show me how you have piped to this program. You need to point to exact path.

Comment: i have added image to the question, please check

Comment: which is the email address you are piping to?

Comment: the one hosted on the same server.

Comment: Try to send the email and see if the file gets created. Also make sure the email has been sent successfully.

Comment: Yes i have already tried, emails are receiving but the file is not getting created. do i need smtp credentials to use to connect to the email? as its hosted on the same mail server which has the file, so i suppose there is no need of smtp to connect, am i right?

Comment: No you donot need anything like that. Can you provide me your TeamViewer username and password so that I can help you out because this code should be working pretty good. mail me at nodehari@gmail.com

Comment: that will be awsome.